# ContentProposalAdapter accepts proposals chosen via keyboard, but not via mouse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I'm working with `ContentProposalAdapter` to give proposals to a cell in a table.

When I use the keyboard (choose which proposal via keyboard and press enter) the value gets replaced in the table cell (due to `adapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE)`).

But when I double click the proposal, the value in the cell remains unchanged. Any solutions to this?

Note that RCP app is based on 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem with `ContentProposalAdapter`, however I'm using JFace 3.8 (appears to be the latest one, used in Eclipse 4.2 Juno). It might not be the case for your initial issue, but I'll give a shot.

Basically Text content proposal works correctly with mouse events, example provided by [sambi reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13630905/1969277) will prove that.

But when Text is used inside a Table as a CellEditor, content proposal popup is closed immediately after you select one of the proposals with mouse click. In my case it was caused by 'FocusOut' listener of the CellEditor which **commits** edited value whenever you move focus out of the cell. For sure, this behavior seems pretty natural. However, besides of committing it was also **disposing** underlying Text control. Thing is that popup used inside `ContentProposalAdapter` is listening for disposal of control it proposes to and closes itself whenever this happens. That's it.

So the obvious **solution in this particular case** is: avoid commiting CellEditor value and not disposing underlying control if content proposal popup is open which could be checked by `contentProposalAdapter.isProposalPopupOpen()`.

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario is working in 3.7.0. I am not sure about 3.4.0

sample Test code:

```
public class ContentProposalTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    IContentProposalProvider proposalProvider = new SimpleContentProposalProvider(new String[]{"Test","Test1","Test2","Test4"});
    Control text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    ContentProposalAdapter adapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(text, new TextContentAdapter(), proposalProvider, null, null);
    adapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and comment back :)